# Macvlan interfaces beyond first interface fail to connect.

Tags: networking, dhcp, ip

I've been working on a [project](https://github.com/ddaygold/shoehorn) to build a set of macvlans on ubuntu. The process I'm using comes from [here](http://www.pocketnix.org/posts/Linux%20Networking%3a%20MAC%20VLANs%20and%20Virtual%20Ethernets). In short, I run this set of commands to build and initialize an interface:

```
ip link add link eth0 <name_of_macvlan_dev> address <mac_address_for_macvlan> type macvlan
ip link set <name_of_macvlan_dev> up
dhclient <name_of_macvlan_dev>
```

This process works for the first macvlan I set up. Further macvlans successfully acquire a unique mac, but they fail to ping google.

What am I missing here? Is there material that I should read to become more familiar with macvlans?

Additionally, there seems to be a limit of 10 macvlan devices. After I solve my first problem, is there a way to increase that limit?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must be able to ping the gateway successfully first. To do this, you must disable `rp_filter` on the specific interface，then you should add a route on the interface for a specific address.